# what is the physical significance of this phenomena?

Tags: kinematics, integration

Let's suppose that I'm going to ride a motorcycle, so what I'll do first is accelerate, then I'll achieve some velocity and after that my position will change, mathematically:

$$ \dfrac{d^{2}x(t)}{dt^{2}} \rightarrow \dfrac{dx(t)}{dt} \rightarrow x(t)$$

Here is the integration which takes place step by step. If differentiation is the reverse process of integration then how does it happen in this case?

Comment: I wouldn't say the integration is "step by step".  You've integrated two different times.  You could take 2 derivatives to find acceleration in the same fashion.  It isn't really clear to me what the question is.

Comment: The reason that introductory materials examine motion in cases of constant velocity and constant acceleration *isn't* because there is some physical phenomena that forces motion to have those characters, it's because those are the easy to analyze cases. Real motions essentially never have those characteristics in general but are often close enough to make the math worth doing anyway. In particular we can rig cases where things are close to those ideals pretty easily, and can examine situation in which we know the motion to have approximately one of those characters.

Comment: all i'm trying to say is the phenomenons i.e acceleration, velocity and change of position they are happening one by one related by integration , so how can i represent them through differentiation , because the reverse processing isn't happening here @JMac

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light They aren't happening one by one.  The three things describe different aspects of the system.  Acceleration _is_ a change in velocity which _is_ a change in position.  It's not one leading to the next.  The reason something accelerates has to do with forces, and is not addressed by your equations.

Comment: You have already related them by differentiation. What is the difficulty? What don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is a control system.

First off, it doesn't work the way you said it.  You don't achieve some velocity and *after* that your position changes.  The position is changing fluidly while accelerating.

What's really happening is that your acceleration is not constant, and it's being driven by a control loop in your head.  You choose to open the throttle wide (creating a lot of acceleration) until you get near your desired velocity, then you change the throttle to maintain that velocity (in reality, you will have a little acceleration and deceleration as you wander a little around that velocity).  During the whole time, your position is the integral of your velocity.

Comment: I don't think he was thinking of a control system, I think he is just very confused on the basic equations of motion and derivatives.  In my opinion this answer may further confuse the topic.

Comment: no @jmac i am well acquainted with " basic equations of motion and derivatives" i think  you somehow misinterpreted my question , and yes i was referring to a PD or a Derivative controlling action and your answer really helps thanks Mr.cort Ammon

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light Then you need to really look into clairifying questions.  Your question was extremely vague, one mention of control systems would have cleared it up quite a bit.  There is literally no mention of that.

Comment: Sorry i'm new on PSE , i'll keep that in mind from next time , thanks anyway @JMac